# How to properly configure WAS Liberty server.xml basicRegistry with MobileFirst Server and AdminCenter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-server

I'm trying to install the latest version of MobileFirst Server 7.1 onto WAS Liberty 8.5.5.9 and am having difficulty enabling login for the installed WARs.  This is a brand new installation.  adminCenter-1.0 was installed before installing MobileFirst Server.

[This page](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/t_troubleshooting_basicregistry_authentication_failure.html) describes the root issue, but there appears to be something missing from the instructions.  The instructions as written don't make sense to me in that in one sentence it says to "move" content added by the installation process, but in another sentence in that same paragraph says to "delete" it from server.xml.

As I've interpreted the instructions, I now have two basicRegistry elements with different ids as follows:

```
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
    <user name="admin" password="adminpwd" />
</basicRegistry>

<!-- Declare the user registry for the Application Center. -->
<basicRegistry id="applicationcenter-registry" realm="ApplicationCenter">
    <!-- The users defined here are members of group "appcentergroup", thus have role "appcenteradmin", and can therefore perform administrative tasks through the Application Center console. -->
    <user name="appcenteradmin" password="admin"/>
    <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
    <group name="appcentergroup">
        <member name="appcenteradmin"/>
        <member name="demo"/>
    </group>
</basicRegistry>
```

But what I don't see is how to tie the new applicationcenter-registry to the MobileFirst Application Center.  And sure enough, this configuration doesn't allow me to log into the WAS adminCenter, or the MobileFirst Application Center.  It also generates the message that you'd expect:

> There are multiple available UserRegistry implementation services; the system cannot determine which to use.

What is the proper server.xml configuration that will allow me to log in to both of these applications?

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the server.xml, you can only have one basicRegistry. The documentation basically tells you to copy the content inside the `<basicRegistry id="applicationcenter-registry" realm="ApplicationCenter">` 
to your `<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">`

Then remove `<basicRegistry id="applicationcenter-registry" realm="ApplicationCenter">`
so you only have one basicRegistry, your own 
`<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">`, in the server.xml.

Check your server log to see if there is any error.  If there is error related to the database, make sure your database is accessible and it has been started with root/admin right.

Comment: For anyone that got here by the error, you can't really have two `<basicRegistry>`tags in the server.xml, but if you are working with IBM MFP docker container image, the xml configurations might mislead you. You see no `<basicRegistry>` in the server.xml, but it's in registry.xml file override under /usr/config directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the instructions are saying you should do this:

```
<basicRegistry id="basic" realm="BasicRealm">
    <user name="admin" password="adminpwd" />

    <!-- Declare the user registry for the Application Center. -->
    <!-- The users defined here are members of group "appcentergroup", thus have role "appcenteradmin", and can therefore perform administrative tasks through the Application Center console. -->
    <user name="appcenteradmin" password="admin"/>
    <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
    <group name="appcentergroup">
        <member name="appcenteradmin"/>
        <member name="demo"/>
    </group>
</basicRegistry>
```

i.e., you should have a single `<basicRegistry>`, and it should contain your original users/groups (if any) and the users/groups for Application Center.

Comment: Thanks Brett, but that's (except for the admin user being last in the block) identical to what the Mobilefirst Server installation process put in that block.  That approach unfortunately didn't work for me and is what led me to the lined page in the documentation above.